# display image using gstreamer with c API

Tags: c, gstreamer

i  try to do a gstreamer pipeline using c API to show image for this i use this gst-launch command

```
gst-launch filesrc location="pluto.jpg" ! jpegdec ! ffmpegcolorspace ! videobalance saturation=0 ! freeze ! ximagesink
```

when i try it it work fine but when i try to convert it to c code it doesn't work someone can help me please ?

```
#include <gst/gst.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  GstElement *pipeline, *jpdec, *imgf, *cod, *source, *sink;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;
  GstStateChangeReturn ret;

  /* Initialize GStreamer */
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  /* Create the elements */
  source = gst_element_factory_make ("filesrc", "source");
  sink = gst_element_factory_make ("ximagesink", "sink");
 jpdec = gst_element_factory_make ("jpegdec", "jdec");
 imgf = gst_element_factory_make ("imagefreeze", "freeze");
 cod = gst_element_factory_make ("ffmpegcolorspace", "ffmdec");

  /* Create the empty pipeline */
  pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("test-pipeline");

  if (!pipeline || !source || !sink || !jpdec || !imgf || !cod) {
    g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
    return -1;
  }

  /* Build the pipeline */
  gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), source, jpdec, cod, imgf, sink, NULL);
  if (gst_element_link (source, sink) != TRUE) {
    g_printerr ("Elements could not be linked.\n");
    gst_object_unref (pipeline);
    return -1;
  }

  /* Modify the source's properties */
   g_object_set (G_OBJECT (source), "location","pluto.jpg", NULL);

  /* Start playing */
  ret = gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
    g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
    gst_object_unref (pipeline);
    return -1;
  }

  /* Wait until error or EOS */
  bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);
  msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

  /* Parse message */
  if (msg != NULL) {
    GError *err;
    gchar *debug_info;

    switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)) {
      case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
        gst_message_parse_error (msg, &err, &debug_info);
        g_printerr ("Error received from element %s: %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), err->message);
        g_printerr ("Debugging information: %s\n", debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
        g_clear_error (&err);
        g_free (debug_info);
        break;
      case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
        g_print ("End-Of-Stream reached.\n");
        break;
      default:
        /* We should not reach here because we only asked for ERRORs and EOS */
        g_printerr ("Unexpected message received.\n");
        break;
    }
    gst_message_unref (msg);
  }

  /* Free resources */
  gst_object_unref (bus);
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);
  return 0;
}
```

there is the c code that i use to play image
when i compile the code i don't have errors but when i run it i  have this erreur :

```
(test:5355): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_caps_get_structure: assertion `GST_IS_CAPS (caps)' failed

(test:5355): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_structure_get_int: assertion `structure != NULL' failed
Error received from element sink: Failed to create output image buffer of 0x0 pixels
Debugging information: ximagesink.c(472): gst_ximagesink_ximage_new (): /GstPipeline:test-pipeline/GstXImageSink:sink:
could not get shared memory of 0 bytes
```

Comment: Those don't look like compile-time errors.  Are you sure they're not run-time errors? (do you know what the difference is?)

Comment: no i don't know the difference can you explain please?

Comment: Step 1 is to ***compile*** your program, to change it from source-code into computer code.  You may get errors during compile-time.   After your program compiles successfully, Step 2 is to ***run*** your program to actually execute the computer code.  You may get a different set of errors during run-time.   Did you get these errors when you ***compiled*** your program, or when you ***ran*** your program?

Comment: No i don't have any erreors when i compile the code

Comment: i compile it whith this command gcc image.c -o test `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-0.10` and it's ok i don't have errors ,but when i run it with ./test it show me the errors that i pas it in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gst_element_link is wrong. Something like:

```
if (gst_element_link_many (source, jpdec, cod, imgf, sink, NULL) != TRUE)
```

should work.

Those errors are likely a bug in xvimagesink, but you are using it wrongly. Feel free to report a bug at bugzilla.gnome.org about these assertions in case they happen with 1.0.